# Validation loss or accuracy doesn't improve

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I'm training a dataset (CT scan images) using VGG network.
I recieved following diagrams. The issue with its diagrams is, I can't see there validation oss or accuracy getting improved, though accuracy and loss improved.

Here are my diagrams. Can anyone give me about the insights or suggestions for this issue

[image]

[image]

Comment: elaborate more about the data and post the code

Comment: It’s baffling to think that your validation accuracy is consistently so much higher than your training accuracy. Are those labels backward?

Comment: Hi Arya.. May I know what you meant by labels backward?